# script to Automatically backup heroku postgreql DB and download dump file to local

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, postgresql, heroku

I have a Ruby app on heroku (postgresql DB) and  want to have a script that is fired from windows server task scheduler to make a backup of the postgresql DB and download it to local machine as a daily backup.

I can do this manually using
heroku pgbackups:capture --expire -a app_name
curl command.
But would like to automate this process

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use your **backup command** in a [Batch File](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758944%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) in the [Windows Schedule](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc748993.aspx) to do this aumomatcly.